# Does Angular link function trigger change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular directive with a `link` function and inside it I'm instantiating a jQuery plugin, as seen here https://plnkr.co/edit/58nOhypt6FRdI4At5jwu .

The problem is that every moment the directive is instantiated, it triggers a `change` event and I have a function listening those `change` events (when they are triggered by the user).

Does the `link` function always triggers `change`? Or is it the jQuery plugin doing it? I'm receiving a value (that came from an Ajax request) and putting it in the input. The plugin should not "touch" it, it should just instantiate the datepicker.

Another point is: let's consider that the plugin changes the input. This is a **programmatic** change and the `ng-change` directive does not listen for these programmatic changes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `link` function **does not** `trigger` the change event. The change event is being triggered by this code:

```
$datepicker = $(element).datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: 'today',
        language: 'pt-BR',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        forceParse: false
      });
   $datepicker.datepicker('setDate', date);
```

which actually changes the model `$scope.date`, that's why the `ng-change` is being called!

that will answer this question:

> Another point is: let's consider that the plugin changes the input.
>   This is a programmatic change and the ng-change directive does not
>   listen for these programmatic changes, right?

In another words:

> Basically you are changing the format of the input during the link
>   event.

You can workaround by telling your `edit()` function when the real change happens or you can simply do a simple `watch` and don't use the `ngChange` directive.

```
$scope.$watch('date', function(newValue, oldValue) {

    if(newValue!=oldValue&&newValue!='25/12/2018'){
      console.log(newValue);
      console.log(oldValue);
      $scope.changed = true;
    }
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Yq32mq7fm7niy6eXhrDL?p=preview

In my opinion, if you may. **I won't be using any jQuery in the project**.

You should be using **Angular ui-datepicker** https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

About **Angular** with **jQuery** [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) :

> DOM Manipulation Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in
>   controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements,
>   retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in
>   directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM
>   manipulation. See below about duplicating functionality.
>
> If you're struggling to break the habit, consider removing jQuery from
>   your app. Really. Angular has the $http service and powerful
>   directives that make it almost always unnecessary. Angular's bundled
>   jQLite has a handful of the features most commonly used in writing
>   Angular directives, especially binding to events.

Comment: OK! I was wondering about using a `watch` instead of `ng-change`, but I will have a lot of watches (I have a list of items, each one with a date property) and this could make my UI slower...

Comment: @VictorLeal don't use `watch`. I only suggested you `watch` as a **workaround**. My main answer is  stop using **jQuery** and import the  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker in your project, so will not need to configure the `datepicker`  like you are doing it.

Comment: I'm doing some tests!